# Forward locking an image file Android

Tags: android, file, encryption, sd-card

In Android 2.2 and above,Is there any way i can prevent the (encrypted) file in the SD card from being deleted/renamed/moved? Atleast prevent that using file explorer applications like ES file explorer? Assume no rooting is done.

In android 2.2 and above, there is a folder android-secure. This contains encrypted files with ext *.asec(I Understand this is used by Android system to save the apk files securely in the SD card). These files are not visible from ES file explorer. Is there any API to save an image file as .asec in Android?